# The Components are disappearing after importing i18n in my App component

Tags: reactjs

Created i18n.js file as it is said in documentary , and inserted in the file the following code

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

const languages = ["en",  "es", "ar"]



const options = {

    order: [ 'localStorage', 'cookie', 'querystring', , 'sessionStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag', 'path', 'subdomain'],


    lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
    lookupCookie: 'i18next',
    lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    lookupSessionStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
    lookupFromSubdomainIndex: 0,

    caches: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],
    excludeCacheFor: ['cimode'],


    cookieMinutes: 10,
    cookieDomain: 'myDomain',

    htmlTag: document.documentElement,


    cookieOptions: { path: '/', sameSite: 'strict' }
}


i18n

    .use(Backend)

    .use(LanguageDetector)

    .use(initReactI18next)

    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
         lng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        whitelist: languages,
        detection: options,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        }
    });


export default i18n;
```

then imported above mentioned file in App component,
After refreshing the already translated pages, the components are disappearing, but when i am  comment i18n.js  imported file in my App component out  everything is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the browsers console, probably you will find an answer there.

From a quick look at your code, it seems that your `options` object has a type error inside `order` array, an extra comma.

```
..., 'querystring', , 'sessionStorage', ...
```

I would suggest to use eslint so you can find and fix this issues in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks my friend, removed coma from the array and added Suspence fallback